# What change of coordinates makes a black hole an De Sitter space with a white hole at the other side?

Tags: black-holes, coordinate-systems, white-holes

I have seen that Jean-Pierre Petit describes a change in coordinates for the exterior schwarschild solution that connects two minkowski flat spaces:

https://www.jp-petit.org/papers/cosmo/2015-ModPhysLettA.pdf

Could a change in coordinates describe the schwarschild exterior solution with a white hole at the other side in a De Sitter space? And which?

Comment: As far as I can see this is a crackpot paper. The authors have rediscovered Einstein–Rosen bridge (see [here](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.48.73) for the original paper from 1935), yet are arriving to completely wrong conclusions from it.

Comment: But the metric he uses is different from the one that describes an Einstein-Rosen bridge rigth?

Comment: The metric Petit uses is the same Schwarzschild metric with an unusal choice of coordinates. It is related to the ER choice of coordinates in eq. (5a) through $\log \cosh \rho = u^2 $. Note, that this chart does not cover the whole extended Schwarzschild manifold.

Comment: Are you sure? Take into account that he uses the original auxiliary quantity R=3sqrt(r^3+rs^3) with r been the polar coordinate of the Schwarschild original paper. Nevertheless, I dont get why exactly ρ=u^2, althought you are right, the J-P. Petit solution is a wormhole.